# Airflow how to mount airflow.cfg in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, mount

I'm running airflow in a docker container and want to mount my `airflow.cfg` as a volume so I can quickly edit the configuration without rebuilding my image or editing directly in the running container. I'm able to mount my `airflow.cfg` as a volume and my airflow webserver successfully reads the configuration from it on start up. However, when I edit on the host changes aren't reflected inside the docker container.

The output for `findmnt -M airflow.cfg` inside the docker container returns:

```
TARGET                         SOURCE                                                             FSTYPE OPTIONS
/usr/local/airflow/airflow.cfg /dev/sda1[/host/path/airflow/airflow.cfg~//deleted]  ext4   rw,relatim
```

From that output it seems like `airflow.cfg` continues to point to the original unedited version of `airflow.cfg`. Is there any workaround to allow updating the config file from the host machine?

I'm using the LocalExecutor compose file from the [puckel github repo](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) as a base. I modify it to mount `airflow.cfg` in the compose file instead of copying it in the Dockerfile.

Comment: What's your modified docker-compose file look like? It should work when you put it there so I'm guessing something may be wrong in the docker compose file.

I've done the same thing in my docker-compose.yml file. Under `volumes:` it looks like: `local/path/to/airflow.cfg:/docker/path/to/airflow/home/airflow.cfg`

Comment: I specified the volume the same way you're doing it. Have you verified that changes on the host get reflected inside your docker container? My `airflow.cfg` shows up inside the container I just can't change it from the host.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same issue and I solved it by adding the following line to `docker-compose.yml`, under the webserver service

```yaml
- volumes:
  - ./config/airflow.cfg:/opt/airflow/airflow.cfg
```

I have my config file in a folder called `config` where the `docker-compose.yml` file is.

Comment: hey @hamdog, if you found your answer please mark it as "accepted"! This will help the community, cheers

Comment: it creates a folder instead of mounting a file

Comment: The /usr/local/airflow is environment specific, so probably will not work on all envrionments.

Comment: @BertC Hi, this is exactly my doubt. And I asked a similar question on SO. I still didnt get the answer for this. When I setup on local env, it would have a different AIRFLOW_HOME, but when dockerizing, we puckel is copying cfg file to DOCKER env, then how will it work? Do we have to chose the path in both env identically? I think that should not be the right way. I am missing something badly, not sure what. My question link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72778527/docker-airflow-need-to-copy-configuration-file-to-docker-environment. Please help if u can - Voilin , Saverio, Bert.

Comment: the answer is a bit outdated and I don't think it will work properly with the official docker image of airflow. The config file now resides at `/opt/airflow/airflow.cfg`. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: please note that also Yong Wang's answer is valid! For example, in my current configuration, I have everything defined into a file called ".env" e.g. `AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__BASE_URL=mydomain/airflow` and my docker-compose.yaml defined as e.g. `AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__BASE_URL: ${AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__BASE_URL}`. Please check airflow's documentation for a docker-compose.yaml example file

Comment: @SaverioGuzzo Hi ! I'm just wondering, why is it not mounted in the official docker-compose  `https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.2/docker-compose.yaml` ?

Answer (score 10):

In order to quick change airflow config inside a docker container,There are many ways. instead of change airflow.cfg, you can change environment variable directly. In docker container, it can very easy to revise in docker-compose.yml directly.
And you can just restart the docker-compose quickly.

Here is some common configuration variable:

> 1. dag_folder : AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER
> 2. sql_alchemy_conn: AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN
> 3. executor:AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR all configuration variable could be found at [official doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#)

Below is my airflow docker-compose snips

```
 webserver:
     image: apache/airflow:1.10.12
     depends_on:
         - postgres
     environment:
         - AIRFLOW_HOME=/opt/airflow
         - AIRFLOW__CORE_dags_folder=/opt/airflow/dags
         - AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
         - AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR=LocalExecutor
         - AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY=#####youkey################
     volumes:
         - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
     command: webserver
```

Comment: Hi Yong. This is great and it works perfectly. Just setup make changes on environment section of the docker-compose and spin the containers again. However, this doesnt make the changes in the airflow.cfg but sets the environment variable. My doubt is - Is there any way to make persistent changes to config file? And is there a way to really mount the cfg file? If I do it in volumes, it creates a folder instead of file.

Comment: thanks for like the post. I has not play with airflow for many months, so I can just answer your question based on my poor memory. For airflow.cfg mount persistent, it should be OK as I used to tried this way as well.  you may need put the file in right position before the docker first load, otherwise, you many need rm old container.
My airflow config is actual for distribution environment(swarm mode) instead of standalone machine.  The benefit is no need to distribute separate configuration file to remotes servers.