# How to use airflow configuration file (airflow.cfg) when airflow run in container?

Tags: airflow

I'm using Airflow that run in container as described [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html). It seems that the configuration file `airflow.cfg` on the host have no impact on Airflow. I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65189569/3026105) but it didn't help.
The configuration fields I changed are:

```
default_timezone = system #(from utc)
load_examples = False #(from True)
base_url = http://localhost:8081 #(from 8080)
default_ui_timezone = system #(from UTC)
```

I didn't see any impact on airflow eventhough I did `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up`

Comment: You want to specifically use the `.cfg` file or you don't mind achieving what you want using environment variables?

Comment: I know I can use environment variables, but in cfg file I think it is more convinient so I want to be able to use the cfg file