# Airflow up and running but airflow.cfg file not found

Tags: airflow

I have set up the Airflow environment but can’t find the airflow.cfg file.Things that I have done so far:

- Have installed Ubuntu on Windows Wsl.
  Have installed Airflow on Ubuntu using the following composer file: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.4/docker-compose.yaml
- Airflow is up and running.
- The task using EmailOperator doesn’t send email.
- Wanted to configure SMTP parameters in airflow.cfg but haven’t found such a file in [local drive and Airflow container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTXP1.png).

How is that that Airflow is up and running but airflow.cfg file is not found? It was the official Airflow composer file that I was using.

Comment: Have you checked the /opt/airflow path ? Also what user you are running this as ?

Comment: Also have you mounted it ? Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55347077/airflow-how-to-mount-airflow-cfg-in-docker-container

Comment: Command 'whoami' returns my linux username.

In docker-compose.yaml file there are the following volumes mounted:
volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins

I can't mount airflow.cfg file in docker-compose.yml file because there is no airflow.cfg file in my linux file system. I can't understand why.
Command 'find /home -name "*.cfg"' gives empty output.

Comment: /opt/airflow directory has the following content:
> ./airflow.sh bash
Creating airflow_airflow-cli_run ... done
default@2232c5571b24:/opt/airflow$ ls -la
total 24
drwxrwxr-x 1 airflow root 4096 Apr 11 11:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root    root 4096 Feb 22 20:12 ..
drwxr-xr-x 6 default root 4096 Apr  7 14:50 dags
drwxr-xr-x 9 default root 4096 Apr  7 15:28 logs
drwxr-xr-x 2 default root 4096 Mar 27 09:33 plugins

Why the airflow.cfg file isn't mounted in docker-compose.yml by default?

Comment: No idea why but you can create one which is per your requirements and mount it. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Docker-compose, you don't modify the file `airflow.cfg`. Instead, you add environmental variables to the docker compose.

For instance, you see in the compose that there is the line

```
AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
```

Which modifies the setting sql_alchemy_conn that would be in the airflow.cfg https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#sql-alchemy-conn

You can find the environmental variables equivalents in the link above for all the settings in the config. Anyway, the rule is pretty simple:

```
AIRFLOW__SETTING SECTION__SETTING NAME: VALUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-config.html#setting-configuration-options) the airflow.cfg file should created in $AIRFLOW_HOME directory (~/airflow.cfg by default).

Alternatively, you could also look up the value assigned to the environment variable with `echo $AIRFLOW_HOME` command.

Another option would be to navigate to https://localhost:8080/configuration (Airflow UI) in the browser. It will display the path to the `airflow.cfg` file on the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Happened the exact same to me!

I installed Airflow via pip. It turned out somehow I have different Python versions installed, and pip was *not* Python3 but Python2 pip.

After uninstalling Airflow, I did the exact same stuff, but replaced with pip with pip3 in commands.

After it, I got the correct config file at the correct place (`~/airflow/airflow.cfg`)