# Docker Airflow - Need to copy configuration file to docker environment?

Tags: docker, airflow

I am learning to create my own Airflow image and for that, I am going through famous puckel's docker image for airflow. In that code, I have a doubt related to the airflow configuration file.

Some part of his **Dockerfile** looks like this,

```
COPY script/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh   --------> 1
COPY config/airflow.cfg ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}/airflow.cfg -------> 2
 
RUN chown -R airflow: ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}

EXPOSE 8080 5555 8793

USER airflow
WORKDIR ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["webserver"]
```

And, some part of **entrypoint.sh** looks like this,

```
case "$1" in
  webserver)
    airflow initdb
    if [ "$AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR" = "LocalExecutor" ] || [ "$AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR" = "SequentialExecutor" ]; then
      airflow scheduler &
    fi
    exec airflow webserver
    ;;
  worker|scheduler)
    sleep 10
    exec airflow "$@"
    ;;
  flower)
    sleep 10
    exec airflow "$@"
    ;;
  version)
    exec airflow "$@"
    ;;
  *)
    exec "$@"
    ;;
esac
```

***My doubt is*** - Isn't copying the configuration file to docker environment redundant in this case as when the `./entrypoint.sh` will run during the docker run command, it will run `airflow initdb` anyway, which will create its own `airflow.cfg` inside the airflow home folder inside the docker? If my understanding is correct, what is the purpose of copying `airflow.cfg`?

Dockerfile [path](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/bed777970caa3e555ef618d84be07404438c27e3/Dockerfile)

entrypoint.sh [path](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/bed777970caa3e555ef618d84be07404438c27e3/script/entrypoint.sh)

Comment: Airflow only generates airflow.cfg if it doesn't exist in `$AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow.cfg`. My hunch is that the `config/airflow.cfg` has been modified by Puckel. You can diff it and the [default_config](https://github.dev/apache/airflow/blob/ff103046617b7ed8edadb179631cc36bb8a359a2/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L21) to see what really changed.

Comment: Part1 - Thanks for your reply, @OluwafemiSule. Actually my concern is not with modifying but it is with the configuration file to the docker env. For example if we see the field dags_folder in the configuration file, it is usually ~/AIRFLOW_HOME/dags, so when configuring the airflow on local development PC, the home could be something like `/user/pankaj/airflow/dags`,but this path could not be present there in the docker environment.If we also copy the airflow configuration file to the docker environment, won't it force us to also use the same absolute home path in the docker environment too?

Comment: Part2- Because otherwise, the airflow wont be able to locate the dags, logs and other folders. My concern is with absolute paths of the airflow home in both the environemnt. As I mentioned above, it could be `/user/pankaj/airlow` in my local PC where I am trying to setup airflow, and it could be `/opt/airflow` inside docker. So, In my opinion, copying the configuration file from local should create problems as it uses absolute paths. Can you please clarify my understanding? and please guide me if I am missing anywhere.

Comment: You might want to use the official Docker image and not the one by puckel. The puckel version has not been maintained overtime.